# ¿Como hago un if en laravel sin imprimir el resultado?

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un if para saber si es admin o usuario, pero me imprime lo que está dentro del if y no quiero eso, solo que me lo muestre dentro de la tabla, ¿como lo hago?.

```html
<table class="striped responsive-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Usuario</th>
          <th>E-mail</th>
          <th>Tipo</th>
          <th>Opciones</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    @foreach($user as $item)
     @if($item->permiso == 0)
      {{$valor = 'Admin'}}
     @else
      {{$valor = 'Cliente'}}
     @endif   
      <tr>
        <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$valor}}</td>
        <td>x</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach()

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al usar los ***dobles corchetes en Blade*** le estas indicando que haga un `echo` de ese contenido, es decir que:

```
<p>{{ $hello }} world !</p>
```

va a imprimir el contenido de la variable `$hello`.

Para hacer una asignación, como creo que es tu intención puedes usar tags de PHP, así:

```
@php $hello = 'Hola'; @endphp
```

Con lo que tu código quedaría:

```
<table class="striped responsive-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Usuario</th>
          <th>E-mail</th>
          <th>Tipo</th>
          <th>Opciones</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    @foreach($user as $item)
     @if($item->permiso == 0)
       @php $valor = 'Admin'; @endphp
     @else
       @php $valor = 'Cliente'; @endphp
     @endif     
      <tr>
        <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$valor}}</td>
        <td>x</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach()

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Como es una linea también es valido `@php($valor = 'Admin')`

Comment: O directamente en el `<td>` podría hacer: `{{ ($item->permiso == 0) ? 'Admin' : 'Cliente' }}`.